# What exactly does Node.js do?

Tags: node.js, web, server

Could someone give me a quick description of what node.js exactly is?  I understand it is a server, but what is a server?  I have basic knowledge of web, but I do not fully understand it.  Do I send requests to node.js and it does a get to my database?

Thanks for anyone who can help!

Comment: "I understand it is a server, but what is a server?" That is not understanding.

Comment: @BrendanAshworth I think he meant it like `I heard it is a "server", but what is a "server"?`

Comment: @chris-l I'll give benefit of the doubt. :)

Comment: @chris-l Sorry that is what I mean!  I didn't mean to write is as a philosophy paper lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node is a platform. It's a platform written in Javascript and C++ that interacts with and calls the underlying operating system so that you don't have to directly. This is what makes it a platform, basically(not a framework or environment). It's a platform that leverages the Javascript V8 engine so that you can write in Javascript as an abstraction to the lower details of programming; e.g. writing in C and Assembly

A server is anything that serves requests to a requester as a service. If you are serving a request, you are a server. Node is more than just a server. It's a platform that could act as a client too, just like any other program. It can do just about anything a lower-level language or platform can do, so you can think of all the possibilities. Higher-level languages and platforms are viewed as being faster to code than say writing in C.

You can send requests to a node server program that can access a database on behalf of the request and forward the database data to fulfill the request. For instance, if you request a website that generates dynamic data from a database; Node can do this. Node can bind to a network port through the Operating System that a user can connect to and request, such as `http://localhost:8080`. Because you code this in Node with Javascript, it's very high-level compared to what is really going on in Node on your behalf, such as using low-level system calls. These low-level system calls are made internally in Node on your behalf as interpreted by the higher-level language of the Javascript code.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js is a programming environment that allows you to write code in the Javascript language and interact with the rest of the system (instead of being limited to running within a browser). One of the things Node.js can do is act as an HTTP server, in which case the code you write would respond to web requests. One of the things you could do in responding to a request is to look something up in a database and send data to the user's browser.

Answer (score 0):

Not a server, its a server side programming language that is based on Javascript and has a server build in if you want to use it.

The intro [here](http://nodejs.org/) are great for learning the basics.